# Q: How can I change the cell size in UITableView, to show all the labels?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I nearly finished making my tableview cell and all the contents in data model shows up in the UI so I think the connection is fine. The problem is that my prototype cell shows only part of what it's supposed to show. I have 3 labels in the cell, but it only shows one and a half. [the text is stuck to the left(I wanted to put it in center), and the textlabel is cut off so it doesn't show in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxlgu.png).
It's supposed to look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pSR4.png)

I tried

`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`

this code in the ViewController to make my cell to automatically set height to my labels, but it didn't work. 
I also used vertical stack view and made constraints so it fills the cell fully, and it doesn't seem to make a change.

Please help!

Comment: show code what you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use implement the UITableViewDelegate protocol and the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

where you can return the custom height for each cell

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Storyboard - you can just drag a cell in the UITableView to be bigger. The UI of resizing the table view cell is the same as resizing any UI element in the Storyboard. The rest of them will be too, though. Hope this helps!